# how to make an option in select looks in the front end as selected while using ngModel in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

```
               ` <ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
                 <ng-container *ngIf="selectedToUpdate==item._id">
                   <div class="row">
                       <div class="col">
                               <label for="" class="label">Select type de Controle: <select  
                                  [(ngModel)]="newData.typeControle" name="" id="" class="form-control">
                                   <option value="Revue" [selected]="newData.typeControle ===  
                            'Revue'">Revue</option>
                   <option value="Audit flash" [selected]="newData.typeControle === 'Audit flash'">Audit                    
                        flash</option>
                          </select>
                         </label>
                   <div *ngIf="emptyTypeControle" class="text-danger">{{ emptyTypeControle }}</div>
                 </div>
                </div>
                       </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>`
```

actualy in this case i want in the form when the user is going to update in the selected to be shown what exist in the data JSON response , it workes only when i remove [(ngModel)]="newData.typeControle" it works fine

i tried many things , but it only work when i remove ngModel